# How to get username and password?

Tags: support

This question is in continuation with [How to login when yahoo is blocked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284542/how-to-login-when-yahoo-is-blocked)

but unfortunately its closed.I tried to follow the duplicate question but it says username and password.So my question is how will I get username and password.

At first I tried with clicking on *Log in using Stack Exchange* and there I provided my yahoo username and yahoo password.But it says *We could not find an account for that email address.* and so I tried to signup but it gives an error as shown in the below picture

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the "contact us" link? That goes to SE support staff and may get a faster response than asking in meta on a Sunday.

Comment: @MichaelT No I havent.I thought there are many SE employees here in meta so they can solve my problem easily

Comment: There are indeed overlaps... But it is one thing to post in meta and wait for one of the SE employee to read it (not all do, nor do they all have the fanatic badge). It's another thing to use a form that will put it in their support queue so that they, and all the others who are more active on other SE sites (over 100 of them) could help you.  The SE employees who read gaming or cooking are just as capable of helping you with this issue (no, don't post it on every meta). Thus the support mail would likely be a better approach.

Comment: Try visiting https://openid.stackexchange.com and registering there. Then you should be able to add a Stack Exchange login to your account on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @animuson cool,This way worked

Comment: In which way it is unclear,if its unclear then how @MichaelT responded and how animuson replied.If its unclear then why animuson didnt close this question being a moderator